# Get the first group of regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get first match for number in brackets and expect to get 123, but:

```
String str = "ABC 123-(456)-(789)";
String regex = ".*\\((\\d+)\\).*";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
m.find();

System.out.println(m.group(1)); // "789"
```

Please help.

I found workaround but without matcher:

```
String[] arr = str.split("[\\(\\)]");
for (String s : arr) {
    if (s.matches("[-+]?\\d+")) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something tells me that `...` may contain some important information. Post minimal but complete code which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: why dont you just split the string with space then return the index of 1 with regex of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Sure. It's my firs post so i did some mistakes.

Comment: Do update your question use [edit] option.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile so it can't produce any results. Take your time and post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Ok. Next time i'll be more accurate.

Comment: If your questions will not be seen as good ones (when they will start gathering downvotes or close votes) you can expect your account to be banned from asking new questions. Remember that purpose of Stack Overflow is to be repository of programming questions and answers which should help others in the future. If your question doesn't describe problem properly it can't be helpful for others which means it doesn't belong here. So try to improve quality of your every post if you wish to avoid potential ban. So like I said earlier take your time, and [edit] your question with proper SSCCE.

Comment: I see your question improved a lot! Good job! Now since we are able to reproduce your problem we can explain what problems it has. I posted my answer below. If you have more questions feel free to ask them.

Answer (score 6):

Problem with your regex is that by default `*` quantifier is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), which means it will try to match as much as he can. Since you used it with `.*` it means that it will try to match max of *any* characters since that is what `.` represents (except line separators).

So your regex `.*\((\d+)\).*` will match

```
           ABC 123-(456)-(789)
.*        -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
((\d+)\)  ---------------^^^^^
.*        -empty
```

To change behavior of `*` and make it [reluctant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) add `?` like `.*?`.

But in your case it looks like you should remove `.*` from your regex since you probably don't actually want to match part which they describe. So try with

```
String regex = "\\((\\d+)\\)";
```

and for string like `"ABC 123-(456)-(789)"` you should get result `456` - since it is first result matching this regex. To move to text result `789` you need to use `find` method again.

So your code can look like:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)");
//we make Pattern static field since to avoid recompiling
//same pattern each time we call our method
static String myFind(String text){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()){
        return m.group(1);
    }else{
        return null;//or empty string, or maybe throw exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. It's is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `\\b((?<number>\\d+)\\b)` like this:

```
String str = "ABC (123) (456) (678)" ;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b((?<number>\\d+)\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: you might want to upvote it and accept it if it solved your problem. This is our way of saying "Thanks. It helped" ;) check the basic guidelines there: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @jopasserat OP can't up-vote anything yet (it requires 15 reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). But you are right about accepting answer.

Comment: Ok. I'm new here. And i vote when i have enough reputation.